# How to draw on a image and save

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to draw on my pictures and save it.

I could draw on canvas by using Windows.UI.Input.Inking (thanks to [InkPen-sample-in-CSharp](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/InkPen-sample-in-CSharp-189ce853)), but I have no idea to draw on image and save it.

I found [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) by googleing.
Is it possible by using WriteableBitmapEx to draw on picture and save it ?
or is it difficult for c# ?

Comment: Given a WriteableBitmap, you can save it with the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541240/save-canvas-with-background-image-on-winrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WriteableBitmapEx, you can use SharpDX or Direct2D natively or edit pixels of a WriteableBitmap directly. The link Shahar gave you in a comment should help too. I'd recommend SharpDX with [XAML interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) for best quality and control over the drawing methods.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use WriteableBitmapEx this time because directx is a bit difficut for me. and I could draw on my picture!